# automount stops working due to hanging mount.nfs processes that leave /etc/mtab~ lock file

Tags: nfs, automount, autofs

I've got many automount entries in LDAP for mounting ~200 nodes between each other. 
Often, the automounter stops working. After debugging, I figured out that it can be fixed by running

```
rm -f /etc/mtab~*
restart autofs
```

which makes me think, that there are mount.nfs processes that somehow fail to remove the lock files (they are sometimes called /etc/mtab~.[0-9]*), which prevents the following mount requests to succeed. As a workaround I have a cron job removing the lock files, but it is sometimes too late.

Now the details:

```
System: Linux 2.6.32-33-server #70-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 7 22:28:30 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
automount -V: 5.0.4
mount.nfs -V: linux nfs-utils 1.1.6
```

LDAP entries (relevant lines):

```
objectClass: automount
cn: myhost
automountInformation: -soft myhost:/var/tmp
```

a successful mount looks like this (mount | grep auto):

```
myhost:/var/tmp on /var/autofs/net/myhost type nfs (rw,soft,sloppy,addr=10.x.x.x)
```

whenever I access a new mountpoint, automounter spawns following processes (ps .. | grep mount)

```
/bin/mount -t nfs -s -o soft -f myhost:/var/tmp /var/autofs/net/myhost
/sbin/mount.nfs myhost:/var/tmp /var/autofs/net/myhost -s -f -o rw,soft
```

if I try to run the command manually, I get following message:

```
Cannot create link /etc/mtab~
Perhaps there is a stale lock file?
```

Every following request to the automounter then fails.

**My question now** is how to make automounter behave correctly in the case of mount.nfs processes failing to remove the mtab~ lock file to allow all my hosts mount each other?
Is it a matter of LDAP, NFS, automounter or mount.nfs options?

Please help me to get behind this problem!

Comment: The number suffixes are almost certainly PIDs.   So you know the PID of the stuck mountd, probably.   Try running a system call tracer on them to find out what's up with them.

Comment: That was also my guess, but there are no processes with that PIDs (and also no other "mount" instances in the memory).

Comment: In that case I would fall back on generic troubleshooting; for example running the system call tracer on automountd to find out why it appears to be stuck.